# Run some code once in lib.rs to configure logging?

Tags: logging, rust, initialization, libraries, rust-crates

I have found [std::sync::Once](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html#). But as far as I can make out it seems that that code in that example has to be run inside a function. If I put the example code outside a function I get

```
75 | START.call_once(|| {
   |      ^ expected one of `!` or `::`
```

(... and naturally those suggestions don't apply).

The specific thing I want to do is configure logging in a utilities crate. Any of the functions in this crate could be called first... At the moment I'm having to allow for any of these functions possibly having to run `config_logging`.

NB I've also found that logging configuration also appears to be local to each crate. I.e. each crate needs to configure its own logging. There may be ways round that for all I know, but obviously I don't want to have to pass an extra parameter to each function in this library crate.

Comment: Either run the code at the beginning of every exported function (using a helper function of course), or, if the code is very perf-sensitive, export an `init()` function (but then the interface needs to be unsafe).

Comment: " I've also found that logging configuration also appears to be local to each crate" no ?

Comment: @Stargateur. No? No question mark?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks. Just tried that simple `init` solution, but I didn't seem to need `unsafe`: I probably haven't understood properly. I suppose I was hoping there might be a point, a hook, at which a called crate is "loaded" during execution: I'm probably thinking too Pythonically.

Comment: It depends on how you access the value after it has been initialized (or not). If it's an `Option` (or `OnceLock`) and you `unwrap()` it, then yes, it is not unsafe, but then you can just init it at the same time. It'll be exactly as performant, but more convenient for users.

Comment: There is an option to run code at dll/so load/unload, but Rust std doesn't include it. It can be used with the [`ctor`](https://docs.rs/ctor/latest/ctor/) crate, however there are serious drawbacks: since the Rust runtime may not be initialized, you cannot use pretty much anything.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Again, not too clear about that point. No persistent (user) object is created during this process. I'll just add the code I'm talking about... the sole result is to make the logging macros `info!`, `warn!` etc. actually do something.

Comment: Okay, then you have the option of an `init()` function, or init the `Once` at the entry of each exported function.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Actually crate `ctor` looks pretty great. I won't attempt to understand the drawbacks you mention, and will just hope it emerges one day as a beautiful butterfly...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Chayim Friedman.

All I need to do is this:

```
pub fn init(){
    match config_logging::configure_logging() {
        Ok(()) => (),
        Err(e) => {
            if ! e.to_string().contains("logging system was already initialized"){
                println!("\n\nWARNING. Logging does not appear to have been initialised.\nError was {e}\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... in the called function, which is in its own local `config_logging` crate, I'm pretty sure it is the following line which raises the error if logging for the calling crate has in fact been configured already:

```
log4rs::init_config(config)?;
```

... but this function `init` has to be called explicitly from the caller crate: not great to have to explicitly "initialise" a utilities module.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this using the [rust-ctor](https://github.com/mmastrac/rust-ctor/) crate. It is the equivalent of `__attribute__((constructor))`. However as the other answers (and the `rust-ctor docs!) have said this is generally a terrible idea. You should use an explicit` init()` function instead.

Example code to satisfy the silly rules:

```
static INITED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

#[ctor]
fn foo() {
    INITED.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
}
```